# How can I extend the drawn line to exactly the edge of the square?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create lines that extend from the corner of a square, to a given angle. It works, however it doesn't draw the line to the edge of the square.

I understand that the length is the hypotenuse but I'm unsure of how to retrieve that value in this given instance.

Here's my code:

```
const angle = 32;   // Degree
const offset = 20; // Canvas Padding

let c = document.getElementById("cumulatedView");
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");

const x1 = 250 + offset;
const y1 = 250 + offset;
const length =  250;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(offset, offset, 250, 250);
ctx.stroke();

for ( let i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
  x2 = x1 - Math.cos(Math.PI * (angle * i) / 180) * length;
  y2 = y1 - Math.sin(Math.PI * (angle * i) / 180) * length;  

  ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle to demonstrate how it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/3ckyxoeg/1/

Comment: You need the tangent: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/okgdLz2r/

Comment: @ChrisG thank you so much! I definitely need to brush up on my maths. If you want to submit as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: That's ok, this is a math question and thus OT for stackoverflow anyway :)